# Merging columns on alphabetic order

Tags: r, merge, genetics

I have 4 columns that I want to merge.

```
CHR POS EFFECT_ALLELE NON_EFFECT_ALLELE
1   124 A             C           
5   378 C             T  
3   398 T             C  
3   564 G             A
```

I want them to be merged in the following way:
`CHR:POS:EFFECT_ALLELE:NON_EFFECT_ALLELE`

However, I want "EFFECT_ALLELE:NON_EFFECT_ALLELE" to be merged on alphabetical order.

So for the lines above it would be:

```
1:124:A:C  
5:378:C:T  
3:398:C:T  
3:564:A:G
```

So, for the third and fourth example above it has to be "NON_EFFECT_ALLELE:EFFECT_ALLELE'

Can anyone help me with the coding of merging "NON_EFFECT_ALLELE" and "EFFECT_ALLELE" on alphabetical order?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can `sort` the data first and do `paste`

```
df1[3:4] <- t(apply(df1[3:4], 1, sort))
do.call(paste, c(df1, sep=":"))
#[1] "1:124:A:C" "5:378:C:T" "3:398:C:T" "3:564:A:G"
```

---

Or this can be done in a vectorized way instead of looping through each row to do the `sort`ing

```
with(df1, paste(CHR, POS, pmin(EFFECT_ALLELE, NON_EFFECT_ALLELE), 
        pmax(EFFECT_ALLELE, NON_EFFECT_ALLELE), sep=":"))
#[1] "1:124:A:C" "5:378:C:T" "3:398:C:T" "3:564:A:G"
```